# How to convert node.js array-buffer to javascript array buffer

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, http

I send audio to client using node.js : 

`res.send(audio); / audio it is the buffer array`

And I get object 'arrayBuffer' in data.

[image]

And I conver it to Blob and after to file (I want to get dataURL to show it in player)

```
.then(
        (result) => {
           result.arrayBuffer().then(function (data) {
                const blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'audio/wav' });
                var fileReader = new FileReader();
                fileReader.readAsDataURL(blob);
                fileReader.onload = function (evt) {
                    // Read out file contents as a Data URL
                    var url = evt.target.result;
                    res({blob, url})
                };    
            })
        }
)
```

And it works good. I use this url it as `src` of my `<audio>` attribute and it works.

But now I want to send this file from server as a part of json. Now I get audioBuffer from the serve in "audio" property. I chage arrayBuffer method to json in fetch:

```
result.json().then(function (data) {
       const blob = new Blob([data.audio], { type: 'audio/wav' }); 
       ...
```

[image]

But now it doesn't work. I tried to use module [`www.npmjs.com/package/to-array-buffer`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/to-array-buffer) to convert data.audio to js-arrayBuffer, but it doesn't help.

Maybe you know what's problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved problem. I  use module about whick I wrote [to-array-buffer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/to-array-buffer), but I use not `toArrayBuffer(data.audio)` but `toArrayBuffer(data.audio.data)`